# Launch a controller from another controller angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I've got a controller with a http request, and I need to call it from another controller, this is the controller i need to launch:

```
app.controller('getDataCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading) {
$scope.request = $http({
    method: "POST",        
    url: "someurl",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $scope.allTracks = response.data;
    $scope.recentTracks = response.data.Tracks;
}
```

and this is how i tried to call it:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('getDataCtrl')).$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and idea doesn't make any sense. Use a service to share methods across the app

Answer (score 1):

You can use event broadcasting to communicate between controllers :

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.
module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.test = function() {
      // broadcast custom event with some data
      // OR do something with a shared service
      //
      // SomeService.doSomething().then(function() {
      //   $rootScope.$broadcast("SOME_EVENT");
      // });
      //
      $rootScope.$broadcast("SOME_EVENT", "someValue");
    };
  }])
  .controller('SecondController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    // Listen for custom event
    $rootScope.$on("SOME_EVENT", function(event, data) {
      // Call controller function
      $scope.updateData(data);
    })
    // Do whatever you want here
    $scope.updateData = function(data) {
      // MyService.doSomethingElse().then(function() {
      //   ...
      //});
      $scope.data = data;
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<div ng-controller="FirstController">
  <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="SecondController">
  <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
</div>

</html>
```